# Parse key=value pair in awk while key is a variable

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to parse `key=value` pair using `awk` in a bash script

A sample key/value is like:

```
time=2
```

where I can retrieve the value using something like this:

```
echo time="2" | awk -F= '$1=="time"{print $2}'
```

Now I want to put this in a bash script, and use a function to specify the `key` to retrieve the value, basically have an argument, something like this (which does not work) :

```
get_value() {
    variable=$1
    echo time="2" | awk -F= '$1=="${variable}"{print $2}'
}

get_value "time"
```

How should I handle this case?

Comment: you are trying to use shell variable inside awk. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Comment: change `awk -F= '$1=="${variable}"{print $2}'` to `awk -F=  -v variable="${variable}" '$1==variable{print $2}'` note that , you were trying to use bash variable `${variable}` inside `awk`'s scope. you need to make `awk` aware of it by doing `-v ....`